# How to Link custom & local library with 'pkg-config'

Tags: mono, embedding, pkg-config

Is there any way to Link a custom library with pkg-config?
For example:
 'pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2' 
but putting mono 2.8 files in a custom directory.I expect somthing like : 
'pkg-config --cflags --libs ./mono.pc'

Comment: I want to embed every package I need in compiling a managed code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ man pkg-config`

> In addition to specifying a package name on the command line, the full
>   path to a given .pc file may be given instead. This allows a user to
>   directly query a particular .pc file.

So yes, what you posted should work. Did you try it? Did you get an error? What version of `pkg-config`? (mine is 0.26)

Alternatively, you can list additional package directories using the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Is there any way to do this to 'pkg-config'? (I mean how to expose a custom 'pkg-config' path to gcc module?) I want to embed everything!

Comment: The environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is inherited by child processes so that should work. Or maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: I tried that but there's a question: can I make bundle of pkg-config and then use `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`?how?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You export that environment variable.